# oscap-chroot: offline mode is not supported by uname probe

Tags: openscap

We are trying to scan offline mounts using oscap-chroot on ubuntu 20
But we are getting following error:
W: oscap:     Requested offline mode is not supported by uname probe.
Can you please help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately, the offline mode isn't available for uname probe. If your SCAP content contains OVAL uname objects, the results of such definitions will be unknown.